# How to get OMElement value?

Tags: java, xml, apache, axiom

`OMElement.ToString()` returns `<DPID>0d02</DPID>` but how to I get the exact value `0d02` ?

```
String val = OMElement.GetText();
```

returns `java.lang.NullPointerException`

I don't get it.

Added:

Here's more of my code:

```
OMElement elem = null;
OMNode node = null;
String text;
Iterator children = getWSIDListByDPIDList.getChildren();
while(children.hasNext()){
    node = null;
    node = (OMNode)children.next();
    if (node.getType() == OMNode.ELEMENT_NODE) 
     {
       elem = (OMElement) node;
       if (elem.getLocalName().equals("DPID"))
        {
          text = elem.getText();
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [OMElement documentation](http://ws.apache.org/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/OMElement.html#getText()) `getText()` is the right method

This is a simple example:

```
String xml = "<DPID>0d02</DPID>";
StringReader in = new StringReader(xml);
OMElement root = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(in).getDocumentElement();
System.out.println(root.getText());
```

And the output is:

```
0d02
```

Maybe there is something other wrong in your code.

Comment: Turns out - it's indeed ok! I've had an error on totally unrelated manner. Thanks, man.